# Random sin repetición

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

Disponemos del siguiente código:

```
import random

L1= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
L2= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
L3= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
L4= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
```

La pregunta concreta que me gustaría responder:
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la asignación random se produzca sin repetición en los casos L1, L2, L3, L4? Es decir, que nunca se asigne la misma letra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) en su lugar. Es una forma eficiente de obtener valores aleatorios no repetidos de una secuencia dada. Como argumentos toma la secuencia con  los posibles valores y el número de elementos aleatorios que deseas obtener (argumento `k`). Retorna una lista con elementos **únicos**.

```
from random import sample

L1, L2, L3, L4 = random.sample("ABCDEFGH", 4)
```

Solo debes tener en cuenta que como es lógico la lista de posibilidades ha de ser igual o mayor que el número de resultados aleatorios que pretendes conseguir.

Si deseas elegir esos elementos en distintos momentos a lo largo de tu código (o quieres usar `random.choice()` porque te cae bien XD) puedes crear un [generador](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) y cada vez que quieras un elemento nuevo se lo pides usando `next()`:

```
import random


def aleatorio(opciones):
    opciones = list(opciones)
    while True:
        r = random.choice(opciones)
        opciones.remove(r)
        yield r

gen = aleatorio("ABCDEFG")
L1 = next(gen)
L2 = next(gen)
L3 = next(gen)
L4 = next(gen)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es remover las letras que ya han salido.

```
import random

values = list("ABCDEFGH")
L1= random.choice(values)
values.remove(L1)
L2= random.choice(values)
values.remove(L2)
L3= random.choice(values)
values.remove(L3)
L4= random.choice(values)

print(L1)
print(L2)
print(L3)
print(L4)
```

Salida:

```
A
B
H
G
```

Otra solución es reemplazar la letra que salio por `""`

```
import random

values = "ABCDEFGH"
L1= random.choice(values)
values = values.replace(L1, "")
L2= random.choice(values)
values = values.replace(L2, "")
L3= random.choice(values)
values = values.replace(L3, "")
L4= random.choice(values)

print(L1)
print(L2)
print(L3)
print(L4)
```

Salida:

```
F
B
H
A
```