# Crear matriz con números random sin repetir

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices, random

Tengo un problema con un programa bastante inicial, asi que creo que alguien podría ayudarme.

Se pide crear un programa para rellenar una matriz N x N con números enteros al azar, comprendidos en el intervalo (0, N^2), de tal forma que ningún número se repita.

No puedo lograr que ningún número se repita usando `random`, si pueden ayudarme me vendría genial. Les dejo mi código:

```
import random


def crear_matriz(n):
    matriz = []
    filas = n
    columnas = n
    for f in range(filas):
        matriz.append([0]*columnas)
    return matriz

def rellenar(matriz):
    filas = len(matriz)
    columnas = len(matriz[0])
    for f in range(filas):
        for c in range(columnas):
            matriz[f][c] = random.randint(0, orden**2)
            
            
    return matriz


def imprimir(matriz):
    filas = len(matriz)
    columnas = len(matriz[0])
    for f in range(filas):
        for c in range (columnas):
            print("%3d" %matriz[f][c], end= "")
        print()


orden = int(input("Ingrese el orden de la matriz: "))

matriz = crear_matriz(orden)

rellenar(matriz)

imprimir(matriz)
```

Comment: Haz una lista [0,1,2, ...n]. Desordenala con `shuffle`. Luego recorre la matriz llenandola. Por cada celda haces `pop()` de la lista para sacar un valor único y random.

Comment: También puedes buscar en el sitio, hay varias ideas que puedes usar, por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39861/random-sin-repetici%c3%b3n

Comment: Crea un `set` (conjunto de datos sin repeticiones) y luego lo transformas a una lista

Answer (score 2):

Una forma más simplificada de hacer lo que pides en este caso sería crear la matriz con forme se van creando lo número aleatorios. Pero en principio no crearemos una matriz, sino una lista donde añadiremos todos los número y posteriormente haremos las particiones necesarias para crear una matriz. En este caso no nos sirve crear una matriz vacía y luego iterar en ella, eso es una perdida de tiempo.

Nuestra función `rellenar` solo recibirá el tamaño `n`de la matriz y con un ciclo `while True` repetiremos un bloque de código que será el encargado de generar el número aleatorio y con ayuda de un `if` verificaremos que el elemento no se encuentre ya en la lista, luego con ayuda de otro `if` verificaremos que la lista tenga el tamaño de todos los elementos de la matriz (que sería `n*n`) y en ese caso pararemos el bucle. Finalmente retornaremos esa lista pero particionada tal que forme una matriz `NxN`, esto lo hacemos usando la notación de *slices* para partir una matriz (sintaxis `[inicio:fin:paso]`).

```py
def rellenar(n):
    pre_matriz = []
    while True:
        num = random.randint(0, n**n)
        if num not in pre_matriz: pre_matriz.append(num) #agregamos a la lista
        if len(pre_matriz) == n*n: break #paramos cuando el tamaño sea el indicado
    return [ pre_matriz[pre_matriz.index(i): pre_matriz.index(i)+n] for i in pre_matriz[0::n]]
```

El código es auto explicativo salvo por la última línea (el `return`) donde para personas con poco conocimiento de python puede resultar difícil de leer, pero lo explicaré.

Estamos usando una comprensión de lista donde se recorre una lista, pero esa lista es solo una lista de `n` elementos que serán los número tomados de `n` en `n` de la lista `pre_matriz` (`pre_matriz[1::n]`) y cada elemento de esa lista será nuestra variable `i` y ahora buscamos ese elemento en nuestra lista con ayuda del método `index` y volvemos a usa los *slices* donde `pre_matriz[pre_matriz.index(i): pre_matriz.index(i)+n]` significa que se creará una lista con los elementos desde la posición en donde se encuentre la variable `i` (`pre_matriz.index(i)`) hasta el elemento en la posición de `i+n` (`pre_matriz.index(i)+n`). El resultado de esto es una matriz `NxN`.

Si queremos que la función reciba una matriz, solo deberíamos de agregarlo a los parámetros y cambiar la primera línea de código:

```py
def rellenar(n, pre_matriz=[]):
    pre_matriz = list(set([e for n in pre_matriz for e in n]))
    #... el resto va igual
```

Y al probarlo

```py
n = int(input("Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz: "))
rellenar(n)
```

obtenemos:

```
Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz: 4
[[33, 256, 183, 158], [70, 187, 235, 48], [184, 169, 205, 40], [200, 178, 240]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener generar números aleatorios sin repetición, primero llenamos una lista con dichos números en orden:

```
secuencia = [x for x in range(n ** 2)]
```

y luego la desordenamos:

```
random.shuffle(secuencia)
```

Ahora sólo queda cortar la secuencia en grupos de *n* elementos y crear una lista de lista (matriz).

```
[secuencia[i:i+n] for i in range(0, n ** 2, n)]
```

#### Demo

```
import random

def matriz(n):
    secuencia = [x for x in range(n ** 2)]
    random.shuffle(secuencia)
    return [secuencia[i:i+n] for i in range(0, n ** 2, n)]

print(matriz(4))
```

produce:

```
[[14, 8, 5, 13], [1, 15, 0, 2], [10, 12, 4, 7], [6, 9, 3, 11]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar la siguiente función que verifica si un elemento existe en la matriz

```py
def exista_el_elemento(elemento, matriz):
    filas = len(matriz)
    columnas = len(matriz[0])
    for f in range(filas):
        for c in range(columnas):
            if(elemento == matriz[f][c]):
                return True
    return False
```

Y en tu funcion `rellenar` agregas lo siguiente dentro de tus `for` anidados:

A la variable `numero_a_agregar` le asignas un numero al azar en el rango que has elegido

```
numero_a_agregar = random.randint(0, orden**2)
```

Mientras tu matriz tenga el elemento que quieres agregar vuelves a generar un numero al azar

```
while exista_el_elemento(numero_a_agregar, matriz):
    numero_a_agregar = random.randint(0, orden**2)
```

Si el `while` termina quiere decir que `numero_a_agregar` no existe en tu matriz por lo que procedes a asignarlo en la matriz

```
matriz[f][c] = numero_a_agregar
```

Al final terminará luciendo asi:

```
def rellenar(matriz):
    filas = len(matriz)
    columnas = len(matriz[0])
    for f in range(filas):
        for c in range(columnas):
            numero_a_agregar = random.randint(0, orden**2)
            while exista_el_elemento(numero_a_agregar, matriz):
                numero_a_agregar = random.randint(0, orden**2)
            matriz[f][c] = numero_a_agregar
    return matriz
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución parecida a las planteadas, puede ser usando `random.sample`. Consiste en coger una muestra de números igual a la cantidad de número de datos.

```
import random
import numpy as np

def matriz_random_unica(tamano):
    total_tamano = np.prod(tamano)
    matriz = np.array(random.sample(range(total_tamano), total_tamano))
    matriz = matriz.reshape(tamano)
    return matriz

matriz_random_unica((3,3))
```

**Salida:**

```
array([[6, 0, 5],
       [2, 4, 1],
       [7, 3, 8]])
```

1. Lo que hacemos es indicamos un tamaño de una matriz.
2. Con `np.prod` multiplicamos para ver cual sería el tamaño si fuese un vector.
3. Con `range` creamos un vector de datos igual al número de elementos que tendra la matriz.
4. Con `random.sample` le indicamos que coja una muestra de tamaño igual al número de elementos, lo que hará que se descoloqué nuestro vector de datos.
5. Por último convertimos con `np.array` a un array de numpy y le aplicamos `.reshape()` para convertir el vector en una matriz del tamaño especificado.

## Bonus

- Numpy es una de las librerías más utilizadas de cálculo númerico en Python, y muy útil para operar con matrices.
- `random_sample` lo que hace es barajar nuestro conjunto de datos.